# Java Unreachable Code in Try Block

Tags: java, try-catch, inputstream, outputstream

I'm working on a chat client that communicates with a server. I recently just changed from using `BufferedReader`s and `PrintWriter`s to using Object streams. I'm curious as to why the print statement is never reached in this snippet of code. I've tried a few things and it appears as if any code after the streams are setup is unreachable. I know that the client has successfully connected to the server because I have it print out the ip address of connected users. Here is the code:

```
try {
    socket = new Socket (hostName, portNumber);
    sIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    sOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("here2");
        String msg = "hi";
        sOut.writeObject(msg);
    }
}
```

Question is: Why is the print statement never reached in this code.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger? Where does it hang?

Comment: Also, have you confirmed that no exception is thrown?

Comment: The issue was on the server's end. I had it creating the in connection before the out connection. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 2):

It most likely is the `ObjectInputStream` constructor blocking.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream-java.io.InputStream-) says this:

> *"Creates an ObjectInputStream that reads from the specified InputStream. A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified. This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header."*

So unless the server side immediately opens a corresponding `ObjectOutputStream` and flushes the stream, the client and server threads will deadlock.

The simplest solution is that the client and server should create and flush their respective `ObjectOutputStream`s before creating their `ObjectInputStream`s.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certain what your problem is. The ObjectInputStream will wait for a header from the other side of the connection / inputStream. It will "hang" until it is received.